# How do I migrate a DB2 Database (app specific instance) from a shared AIX Server to AWS (EC2) server ?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, db2, cloud, database-migration

How do I migrate a DB2 Database (app specific instance) from a shared AIX Server to AWS (EC2) server ? The aix server currently is shared and hosts db2 instances of other apps . I want to migrate only an app specific db2 database instance to Aws possibly running on ec2 as rds does not support db2 . Request help .

Comment: PLANNING comes first. To migrate the *structure* of the database, use db2look on AIX  to capture the DDL and tablespace layouts and grants. Adjust the tablespace/storage-groups/containers according to the provisions of the AWS instance, and adjust security-model according to new security requirements (presumably you will have data encrypted at rest and on network). To migrate the data, either use EXPORT (if there is no connectivity between AIX and AWS) or otherwise pull the data into AWS using scripted load-from-cursor if there is connectivity between AWS and AIX.

Answer (score 0):

[AWS Database Migration Service](https://aws.amazon.com/dms/) is available to convert DB2 source DB to one of the target DB.  DB2 source DB support was added recently (Apr 2018).